# Why can't I bind Elasticsearch and Laravel Scout?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I decided to test Elasticsearch in conjunction with Laravel Scout. I took [this article](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-laravel-elasticsearch/) as a basis

**Attempt #1**

`composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch` - installing ES for Laravel

`composer require laravel/scout` - installing latest version for Scout (9.1)

`composer require tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic` - installing package for ES+Scout

I get this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic[8.0.0, ..., 8.0.2] require laravel/scout ^8.0 -> found laravel/scout[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9.1).
    - Root composer.json requires tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic ^8.0 -> satisfiable by tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic[8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2].
```

I understand for myself that this bundle package has not been updated on github for six months and it is necessary to get to it the necessary version of laravel/scout, so I change the order of actions and do so:

**Attempt #2**

`composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch` - installing ES for Laravel

`composer require tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic` - installing this package hoping that he will get the necessary version of laravel/scout for himself as a dependency, in confirmation of this - I see in the console that he pulled up laravel/scout:8.6.1

Now no mistakes, I'm moving on:

I go to **config/app.php** and add:

```
Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider::class,
ScoutEngines\Elasticsearch\ElasticsearchProvider::class,
```

Run `php artisan vendor:publish`

And now I get new error:

```
Class 'ScoutElastic\ScoutElasticServiceProvider' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you get any solution for this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Solution: don't add `ScoutEngines\Elasticsearch\Elastic search Provider:: class,` to `config/app.php`

Everything works fine without adding this provider

Comment: Its not working. it throws below error. 
Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::setHosts(): Argument #1 ($hosts) must be of type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic/src/LaravelScoutElasticProvider.php on line 23